# It is possible to show ($HALT_{TM}$ is decidable $\Rightarrow A_{TM}$ is decidable), but how about the converse?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines, decidability

Let $HALT_{TM} = \{ \langle M , w \rangle : M \text{ is a TM and } M \text{ halts on } w \}$ and $A_{TM} = \{ \langle M , w \rangle : M \text{ is a TM and } M \text{ accepts } w \}$.

It is possible to show that

> $HALT_{TM}$ is decidable $\Rightarrow A_{TM}$ is decidable $(*)$

by using a Turing machine (TM) $H$ that decides $HALT_{TM}$ to construct another TM $A$ that decides $A_{TM}$ as follows:

> $A =$ "On input $\langle M,w\rangle$,
>
> 1. Run $H$ on $\langle M, w \rangle$.
> 2. If $H$ rejects $\langle M, w \rangle$ then reject $\langle M, w \rangle$.
>
>    - If $H$ accepts $\langle M , w \rangle$ then run $M$ on $w$:
>
>      - If $M$ accepts $w$ then ACCEPT
>      - If $M$ rejects $w$ then REJECT "

However I am having difficulty showing the converse, i.e.

> $A_{TM}$ is decidable $\Rightarrow HALT_{TM}$ is decidable $(**)$

by using a TM that decides $A_{TM}$ to construct a TM that decides $HALT_{TM}$. Is it possible to do this? If it is not possible, how does one rigorously prove that this is not possible?

Here is a natural way to begin to proceed to show $(**)$:

Let $M_A$ be a TM that decides $A_{TM}$. We will try to construct $M'$ that decides $HALT_{TM}$ (But I cannot construct it successfully using $M_A$).

> $M_H =$ "On input $\langle M,w\rangle$,
>
> 1. Run $M_A$ on $\langle M, w \rangle$.
>
>    - If $M_A$ aceepts $\langle M, w \rangle$ then ACCEPT.
>    - $M_A$ rejects $\langle M, w \rangle$ then run $M$ on $w$
>
>      - If $M$ rejects $w$ then ACEEPT.
>      - (Not sure what to do on this line. I know that $M$ will never accept $w$ but I have no way of knowing whether $M$ will never reject $w$, so I can't use $M_A$ to somehow show $M$ will not halt) "

**Comments:**

I find that unintuitive if it is the case that we cannot show $(**)$ because it can be shown that

> $A_{TM} \le_m HALT_{TM}$ (1)

and

> $HALT_{TM} \le_m A_{TM}$ (2)

where $ A \le_m B$ means that $A$ is mapping reducible to $B$ if there exists a computable function $f:\Sigma^* \longrightarrow \Sigma^* $ such that for every string $w$, $w\in A$ iff $f(w)\in B$.

$A_{TM}$ can be shown to be undecidable independent of the undecidability of $HALT_{TM}$ and vice versa, hence we can show $HALT_{TM}$ is undecidable via $A_{TM} \le_m HALT_{TM}$ by virtue of the undecidability of $A_{TM}$ (and similarly show $A_{TM}$ is undecidable via $HALT_{TM} \le_m A_{TM}$ by virtue of the undecidability of $HALT_{TM}$. So because (2) holds, intuitively it seems to me that there should be a way of showing $(**)$?

**Summary of questions:**

1. Is it possible to show $(**)$ by using a TM that decides $A_{TM}$ to construct a TM that decides $HALT_{TM}$. If it is not possible, how does one rigorously prove that this is not possible?
2. If it is the case that it is not possible to show $(**)$, what is really going on because (2) being true seems to suggest that there is a way to construct a TM that decides $HALT_{TM}$ (assuming $A_TM$ is decidable)? Unless there's a good reason that this intuition is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $\texttt{A}_{\texttt{TM}}$ is decidable then $\texttt{HALT}$ is decidable. Better put, a Turing Machine with an $\texttt{A}_\texttt{TM}$ oracle can decide $\texttt{HALT}$ or $\texttt{HALT} \leq_m \texttt{A}_\texttt{TM}$. As stated in the question, $\texttt{A}_\texttt{TM} \leq_m \texttt{HALT}$. The corollary here is that $\texttt{A}_\texttt{TM}\equiv_m\texttt{HALT}$. I will describe the procedure.

For any Turing Machine $M$, if $M$ accepts $w$ then $M$ halts on $w$. If $M$ does not accept on $w$ then construct $\overline{M}$ that rejects a string whenever $M$ accepts it. $\overline{M}$ can be computably constructed uniformly on $M$. If $\overline{M}$ accepts $w$ then $M$ rejects $w$, thus $M$ halts on $w$. If neither $\overline{M}$ nor $M$ accept $w$ then $M$ neither accepts nor rejects $w$, thus $M$ does not halt on $w$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to show in your last paragraph. Can you please clarify by adding details? In Question 1. above I would like a TM $M'$ that decides $HALT_{TM}$ where $A_{TM}$ is some kind of subroutine of $M'$. Is this possible?

Comment: @tcmtan you swap the reject and accept states of the Turing machine and give the resulting Turing machine to the $\texttt{A}_\texttt{TM}$ oracle. You now know whether it accepts on $w$ and whether it rejects $w$. If it does either of these then it halts, if it doesn't then it doesn't halt. Which part do you not understand? The fact that the transformation that swaps the states is computable is necessary for the proof to be valid.